# PHP/MYSQL: Value 0 if record isn't yet in database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following query:

```
$query = "SELECT (SELECT SUM(net_amount) FROM fin_costos WHERE month='1' AND group_of_costos='general' AND year_analysis='2014' ) + 
(SELECT SUM(net_amount) FROM em2_fin_costs WHERE month='1' AND group_of_costos='general' AND year_analysis='2014') AS total";
```

It's basically a `SUM` of 2 values retrieved from different tables.
The problem appears when in one of the `SELECT` statements, the record is not yet in the database and creates a `NULL`, that even if the second `SELECT` gets a value, creates a `NULL`.

The question: How can I turn to 0 the result from the `SELECT` statements if the record is not yet on the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IFNULL()`:

```
SELECT IFNULL((SELECT SUM(net_amount) FROM fin_costos WHERE month='1' AND group_of_costos='general' AND year_analysis='2014' ), 0) + 
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(net_amount) FROM em2_fin_costs WHERE month='1' AND group_of_costos='general' AND year_analysis='2014'), 0) AS total
```

Answer (score 0):

try This

$query = "SELECT (SELECT SUM(case when net_amount IS NOT NULL then net_amount else 0 end) FROM fin_costos WHERE month='1' AND group_of_costos='general' AND year_analysis='2014' ) + 
(SELECT SUM(case when net_amount IS NOT NULL then net_amount else 0 end) FROM em2_fin_costs WHERE month='1' AND group_of_costos='general' AND year_analysis='2014') AS total";

Comment: Thanks. I keep getting NULL for the first SELECT.